# Javascript use of : in function call back protype/passing an array in a callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, operator-keyword

I am trying to use a public JavaScript library one of the callback functions is defined in the documentation as being with an array of objects, I was expecting to define something like

```
bar(foo) {
    alert("Length of object is "+foo.length);
}
```

I get the answer that `foo` is undefined, looking at the calling code in the library, the callback is invoked as

```
register(event,blah,blah,{foo:foo})
```

Q.  What should my callback function look like ?

Comment: As it's a public JavaScript library, perhaps you could link to the API documentation for the function you're trying to use

Comment: have you tested this in fireBug? is `{foo:foo}` defined already?

Comment: I don't really understand the connection between `bar` and `register` and which calls which. Please provide more information.

Comment: There is no documentation or example for using the callback function, its a case of 'use the source'.   The foo:foo function is not defined except in the context off the function.  The register except is a quote from the library,  I do not have access to it at work.  But thaks for thew help folks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `function` keyword for bar isn't missing in your actual code :)...

At a guess it looks like the parameter for the callback is an object, not an array. What do you get for console.log(foo) in the callback?

Are you sure you're actually calling the callback -- have you tried using a function rather than naming the callback function?